# Counting the number of flops

Tags: matlab, pseudocode, flops

For the following pseudocode; I think that the number of flops is 2n^3. However, I am unsure that this is correct as the for loops make me doubt it. (Note: aij and xij represent entries for matrices A and X respectively)

```
for =1:
  for =1:
    for =:
      =+*    
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you explain further why you have any doubts about this?

Comment: Based on past lecture notes, I believe that at k loop, it should have 2(n-j) flops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really a matlab question. Here is a brute force way of working it out.

The inner equation has two flops, so the `k` loop has `2(n-j+1)` flops.

To do the rest, it helps to know the sum of `q` from `1` to `p` is `p(p+1)/2` and `q^2` from `1` to `p` is `p(p+1)(2p+1)/6`.

The `j` loop is of `2(n-j+1)` for `j` from `1` to `i`, so it has `2i(n+1)-i(i+1)=2i(n+1/2)-i^2` flops.

The overall, or `i`, loop is a sum of `2i(n+1/2)-i^2`, giving `n(n+1)(n+1/2) - n(n+1)(2n+1)/6 = n(n+1)(2n+1)/3`.

You can see that this is the same as the sum from `1` to `n` of `2i^2`.

A way to check this, e.g. in matlab, is to set some `n`, and put `f=0` at the start and replace the inner equation with `f=f+2;`, then the result will be `f=n(n+1)(2n+1)/3`.

Comment: How come the k loop doesn't have 2(n-j) flops instead?

Comment: The distance from j to n is n-j steps, but the number of steps including the first and the last step is n-j+1. For example from 1 to n has n-1+1=n steps, i.e. 1,2,...,n, not n-1 steps. From 2 to 4 has 4-2+1=3 steps, i.e. 2,3,4, not 4-2=2 steps.